Why Jenkins found wrong dependency version in my Maven Project
When I launch a Jenkins analyse of my Maven project, i have a security Violation :
Jenkins analyse extract.
the problem is that according to the site https://mvnrepository.com/, version 4.24 of liquibase-core is dependent on version 2.2 of snakeyaml and not version 1.33 mentioned by the analysis report
I don't understand....
my pom file :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sncf.d2d</groupId>
    <artifactId>ro-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ro-server</name>
    <description>RO</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <liquibase.version>4.24.0</liquibase.version>
        <liquibase-maven-plugin.version>4.24.0</liquibase-maven-plugin.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate.version>4.24.0</liquibase-hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Les dependencies :
                org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation
             et
                 org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui
            sont :
                à commenter pour créer des fichiers de migration.
                à décommenter pour utiliser Swagger
        -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <outputChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/migration/1.0_init.postgresql.sql</outputChangeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/migration/_${diff.version}_migrate.sql</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase-hibernate.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                        <version>2.14.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>

                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I tried several things like updating all the dependencies, loading versions 2.2 of snakeyaml myself.... nothing works

Upgrade your spring boot version to most recent 3.3.4 (because 3.1.X is end of support https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) ....Also remove manually defined versions for liquibase because SB already has definition for that...also the poi-ooxml is an old version...(also 5.X version already https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/versions)
